# VBA - How to copy data from a single cell and paste into merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am unable to copy data from a single cell in one workbook and put into merged cells in another, and was wondering if there is a workaround to this. I tried just specifically targeting the first cell of the merged cells as well. For example, if I am trying to paste data in merged cells that consisted of d12:f12...i tried pasting into d12 specifically.

```
Workbooks("Dummy Broadcast.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Copy
Workbooks("TestSheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D12").PasteSpecialPaste:=xlPasteValues
```

Error message is merged cells must be same size

Comment: No need to go through the pasteboard. Try: `Workbooks("TestSheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D12").value = Workbooks("Dummy Broadcast.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad that worked somehow thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to go through the pasteboard. Try:

```
Workbooks("TestSheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D12").value = Workbooks("Dummy Broadcast.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

The above does work, but one can lose the format.

Instead try

```
Workbooks("TestSheet.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D12").Copy
Workbooks("Dummy Broadcast.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormat
```

Comment: The syntax is actually Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats.  Note the additional 's' in the end